# Symfony 5 - Multiple client domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

Not too sure on the best way to go about this. But what i'm trying to create is very similar to a generic shared hosting provider but in Symfony.

Lets say i have a site, myawesomesite.com. Users can signup and have their own space myawesomesite.com/sites/theusersdomain.com/.

I can create a route like this, no problems...

```
    /**
     * @Route("/sites/{client_website_address}", name="client_public")
     */
    public function _client_index($client_website_address) {

        return new Response($client_website_address);

    }
```

Ultimately i would like the user to have their own domain name pointing to this route. Can this be done through Apache VirtualHost? (I will need this for SSL/TLS cert) I have done this but can't figure out how to point to the route.

```
UseCanonicalName Off

LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon

#Client websites
<VirtualHost *:80>

    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myawesomesite.com/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/myawesomesite.com/public">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Will i need to add to my current .htaccess file also? My current .htaccess is standard for Symfony.. (i'll probably combine the .htaccess file with the VirtualHosts later)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have researched a few similar like this but nothing that achieves this, unless there is a better way? I need the domains to be dynamic. The user will go to their URL and their doc root should be my Symfony route (https://myawesomesite.com/sites/theusersdomain.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future Googlers.

I decided to rethink and have come up with an easier solution that should work.

Basically keep the VirtualHosts as is and keep the .htaccess file as is.

I have created a separate Symfony controller for clients homepage by detecting the "host" and matching the requirements with regex.

```
class ClientController extends AbstractController {

    /**
     * @Route("/", host="{domain_name}", requirements={"domain_name"="^(?!(www\.)?myawesomewebsite\.com$).*$"}, name="client_public")
     */
    public function _client_index() {

        return new Response('This is the client web page controller.');

    }

}
```

It will basically detect any other incoming domain other than my own and match. Probably improvements to be made, but for now this seems to work for my requirements.